# Having a tableview and a collectionview in the same screen that hides one or another with a toggle

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm having a problem that I don't know how to proceed.

I need to make a screen that has a Tableview with a header, and when I click on a button in that header, the view should change to a collectionView and share the same header.

I tried putting both in a scrollview (I know it's not the recommended way) but I'm having some problems with the height not showing correct.

In the team I work, we do all the UI programatically.

I would like if someone could share the best way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you keep the header separate between table and collection, Then just toggle 2 views together and still get header here?

Comment: you can put two views one over another. then you enable the one you want and vice-versa. you can even fade out one and fade in the other. that makes a cool transition effect. and with the header you can do whatever you want. keep it separate and update it from the two other views if needed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @son, the header must scroll too, if I scroll the tableview or the collectionview it should be scrolled with the screen

Comment: @ZAY, I was doing something like this, but in a scrollview, but I need the header too scroll with the screen too, if I do it in the controller view, the header keeps fixed and only the tableview is scrolling

Comment: *"... share the same header ..."* -- create two instances of your header view... one for the table view, one for the collection view. When you hide the table view and show the collection view and vice versa, it will look like a "single header view."